# Scraping Metal Archives with Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to do some basic websracping from this website: http://www.metal-archives.com/ with Python:

For example, I want to perform a search for the band Slayer, doing

`requests.get('https://www.metal-archives.com/search/ajax-advanced/searching/bands/?exactBandMatch=1&bandName=Slayer')`

results in `<Response [403]>` however, this was working a few days ago, so I was wondering what happened to metal archives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sites may block HTTP requests or change the response status code and content, based on the client's user-agent, cokies and other headers. We can solve such problems by changing those values.

The most common issue is the user-agent. Sites that don't want to serve automated requests usually blacklist certain user-agents strings, including `requests`'s user-agent ('python-requests/version'). In this case, we can use the `headers` parameter to change the user-agent (and other headers) and get a 200 OK response.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.metal-archives.com/search/ajax-advanced/searching/bands/?exactBandMatch=1&bandName=Slayer'
headers = {'user-agent': 'My-UA'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r)
```

Changing the user-agent to something other than `request`'s default user-agent is usually enough, but some sites may require a valid user-agent string (which we can get from a browser).

This solves this specific issue, but as I said that's not the only reason `requsts` may fail. Another common problem is the cookies. Requests doesn't store cookies by default, but we can change that by using a [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object. However `requests` is just an HTTP client, it doesn't run JavaScript like a browser does. So if JavaScript is the reason for an invalid response, it's best to use [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or similar clients.

Comment: Thank you! These are really helpful information especially for beginners like me.